# How to pass a global variable into a function in C++?

Tags: c++, file, oop, c++11, visual-c++

I am currently learning to parse a file that contains some data on the student's grades.

```
std::ifstream f;

int main()
{
    //std::ifstream f;
    parse_store(f, "student_grades.txt"); //this line is throwing the error

    //keep the window from shutting down
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The `parse_store` function parses the txt file, splits each line of data, then sends the `tokenized` vector (looks like this ["Hello", "World"]) into a class that gets stored in an array of class objects.

for context:

```
//parses the file returning a vector of student objects 
std::vector<Student> parse_store(std::ifstream file, std::string file_name) {

    //array of objects
    std::vector<Student> student_info;

    //create string to store the raw lines
    std::string line;

    // the delimiter
    std::string delimiter = " ";

    //open te file
    file.open(file_name);

    //create vector to hold the tokenized list
    std::vector<std::string> tokenized;

    //index
    int index = 0;
    while (file) { 

        //keep track of the index
        index++;

        //create a vector to hold each student's grades (will hold the objects)
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> grades = {};

        //read a line from file
        std::getline(file, line);

        //delimit the line and send it to the constructor
        tokenized = delimitMain(line, delimiter);
        student_info.push_back(Student(tokenized, index));
    }

    file.close();

    return student_info;
}
```

Why is the line above throwing the error? Is there any problem with the way I am putting the file object into vector and then returning it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass an `fstream` instance by value, because that requires making a copy and iostream objects can't be copied.

You can, however, pass a handle to the `fstream`, allowing the function to use the caller's object without copying.  C++ style calls for a reference, C afficionados might use a pointer.  To use a reference, no change is needed at the caller, just modify the function signature.

```
std::vector<Student> parse_store(std::ifstream& file, std::string file_name)
                              // insert this ^^^
```

---

N.B. It's not clear why you pass both an `fstream` and a file name.  If you pass a file name, the function can create its own `fstream` object and doesn't need one in a parameter.  Or, have the caller open the `fstream` and pass it in; this is more flexible because the caller can also set the position in the file where reading begins.  In that case the function doesn't need the filename, because it is using an already-opened stream.

Comment: As someone who has only programmed in Python and Java perviously, references and pointers are a bit of a novel concept to me. If my understanding is right, by passing in a reference, I am not creating a copy of the object but instead creating a "reference" to the object's memory address but not acting on the object itself? If this is true, how does the function end up creating another fstream object?

Comment: @IkechukwuAnude: Your code as shown in the question didn't pass a reference.  I showed you where to add one character (`&`) to use a reference.  Or were you asking about my note at the end?

Comment: Yes, I was asking about the note at the end.

Comment: @IkechukwuAnude: Which of the two paths did you want to know more about?  Pass (only) `fstream`, or pass (only) filename?

Comment: Pass (only) fstream. But I also have a question: does the rest of the code look like it should function like I described?

Comment: @IkechukwuAnude: For pass only `fstream`, the function signature will be `std::vector<Student> parse_store(std::ifstream& file)` and the caller will look like `fstream f{"student_grades.txt"}; auto results = parse_store(f);`

Comment: The rest of the code looks like all the right pieces are in place, however there still are a few problems.  The variable `grades` is never used.  And you aren't checking the return value of `getline`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have checked for the return value of `std::getline` but I just deleted that piece of code. Will put it in later. Thanks for pointing out that grades is never use, will delete it.